# Using Node.js to stream audio to html5 audio tag and bypass iOS limitation

Tags: ios, node.js, audio-streaming, html5-audio

I'm currently working on a project that use HTML5 audio and we have problems with the limitations on iOS devices (mostly multiple audio channels limitation).

I was thinking that it may be possible to control the sounds server-side using node.js. The client would connect to a single audio url and the node server will stream live sounds trough this single channel doing all the mixing and transitions live on the server.

Is it technically possible? Can you parse audio on node.js and do some live mixing? Do you think the server will explode with more than 5 simultaneous clients?

Thanks

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish that can't be done by pre- processing the audio file?

Comment: @SamDufel for example, a constant background sound with other sounds that can be activated by clicking. Actually we are gonna use a pre processing solution for this specific project but I was thinking that it may be a solution for realtime/dynamic experiences.

Comment: Interesting... I'm not sure that's possible, though, due to cache issues.

Comment: More generally, when you need a continuous background sounds and don't know when other sounds will be played, you're screwed with ios

Comment: *buffer issues,  meant to say. I don't know if there's any way to limit how far the device buffers the audio stream

Comment: I wonder if the new Opus codec might help improve things:
http://www.opus-codec.org/examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible, but as Sam pointed out, buffering is an issue.  There is significant delay that builds up over several points:

- Getting control commands from client
- Mixing raw PCM audio into an internal buffer
- Encoding data with the correct codec (requires you to do this in chunks)
- Sending audio data
- Buffering client-side
- Playback buffer on client-side

Add this all up, and even if you get it working very quickly, you're still looking at a couple seconds delay.

If you do decide to go this route, you'll need an external application (or write your own Node extension) to do the mixing and encoding for you.  Sox is probably a decent choice, and FFMPEG includes many codecs for your use.  You can use both over STDIO.

Regarding server load... this is not a light-weight kind of process, but you would have to profile it to see how bad it really is.  I suggest you make other attempts at playing multiple audio streams at once client-side before attempting something like this.

Comment: Why not use lame? @TooTallNate wrote a nice wrapper for it, https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-lame

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses, LAME is only an MP3 codec.  If you want wider browser support, you need to support more than MP3.  In addition, FFMPEG builds often bundle LAME as a possible codec, so you might as well use FFMPEG to have better support.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link. it works as expected but the issue is client control
[NodeJS Streaming for Audio/Video with Client Side Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012695/nodejs-streaming-for-audio-video-with-client-side-control)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012695/nodejs-streaming-for-audio-video-with-client-side-control
```