# NodeJS Streaming for Audio/Video with Client Side Control

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, html5-video

i am building a simple streaming server to stream audio/video. below code gets the job done but when i click on time line on video nothing happens as i cannot fetch from that time. also need to send event regarding clikc to nodejs streaming and stream from where i clicked.

I had been able to come up with this. i send the file using the URL sendFile="some file" and then the node checks for that file. if successful i start getting the stream on my client side and i put it directly into video src. But i need morecontrol over this. such as when user click on certain timeline so that i can directly start strweaming from there.

app.get is used to get the location of the folder where i store the files.
used just express and nodejs

```
function FolderReaderMerger(path,pathToMerge,cb)
{

  log("Reading File/Folder To Combine : ");
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, audio) 
  {
      fs.readdir(pathToMerge, function(err, audioText) 
      {

         var obj ={};
         global.list.audio =audio;
         global.list.audioText =audioText;

         obj.audio = audio;
         obj.audioText = audioText;

         cb(obj);

      });
  });

}


app.get("/audio",function(req,resp)
{
    log("App Audio File Serv : ");
    var playFile = req.param("playFile");
    var filePath =  {};
    filePath.status =false;


    if(playFile!=undefined)
    { 
    log("Params File : "+playFile);
   /* log("Requested URL : "+req.url);
    log("Total Audio Files : "+global.list.audio.length);*/
    var i =0;
    while(i!=global.list.audio.length)
    {
      if(playFile==global.list.audio[i])
      {
        log("File Found : "+playFile);
        //get files location
        log(app.get("audioPath")+playFile);
        filePath.status = true;

        var filePath = app.get("audioPath")+playFile;
        log("FILE PATH : "+filePath);

        var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
        log(stat);
        log(stat.size);
        resp.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
            'Content-Length': stat.size
        });

        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        // We replaced all the event handlers with a simple call to readStream.pipe()
        log("Streaming.......");
        readStream.pipe(resp);
      }
      else
      {
        log("Requested Resource Not Found");


      }
      i+=1;
    }
    //readStream  = fs.createReadStream(app.get("audioPath"));
    }
    else
    {
      log("Requested Params Not Found");
      resp.send(filePath);
    }
 });



http.listen(app.get("PORT"),function()
{
consolelog("--------------------------------------------------------");
console.log("Server Started On PORT: "+app.get("PORT"));
console.log("All NPM Initialized");
console.log("Please Wait Checking Connection Status...");
console.log("--------------------------------------------------------");

    });



  <video src="http://localhost:3000/audio?playFile='some media file"></video>
```

ANy help would be appreciated.This works on click side

But also need more control regarding click and events.